# Handling radio button events with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a custom styled radio button and handle its event with JavaScript. So the simple task is; add or remove a class when the radio was selected or deselected.

It can be achieved via the `change` event but my problem was the deselection of the radio on a group is not firing the event.

How can I handle this?

P.S
Without using a framework will be better.

Here's my example code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov4L6ud6/)):

```
(function() {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var callback = function(e) {
      e.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          this.classList.add('colored');
        } else {
          // I would like this one to be triggered when
          // the radio button was deselected by the user.
          this.classList.remove('colored');
        }
     });
  }
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(input, callback);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function() {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  var callback = function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('radio-group');
    for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
        if(radios[i].checked ) {
            radios[i].classList.add('colored');;
        }
        else{
        radios[i].classList.remove('colored');;
        }
     }
    });
  }
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(input, callback);
})();
```

you have to go through each radio-button

Answer (score 2):

No need of JavaScript for this. Use CSS `:checked` & `+` selector.

```css
[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="colored" id="option-1" name="radio-group" checked>
<label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="option-2" name="radio-group">
<label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
```

With JavaScript, you have to iterate over radio buttons and remove the class from unchecked radio buttons.

Comment: I am fully aware of this, but I prefer to handle this with JavaScript. Thanks for the info sir, I appreciate it :)